# Javascript Function for Login Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, login-script

I have a login form on our new website design, and it has a username/password input, a drop-down select to choose which part of the site (control panels) to login to, and the submit button. As each panel has different needs to login from an external page, I wrote a Javascript function to match these. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work, and I am lost on where the issue is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeAction(s)
{
    var loginform = document.getElementById("frmLogin");
    panel_option = parseInt(s.options[s.options.selectedIndex].value);

    switch (login_option)
    {
        case 0:
            loginform.action = "https://www.domain.com/clients/dologin.php?goto=clientarea";
            loginform.username.name = "username";
            loginform.password.name = "password";
            break;
        case 1:
            loginform.action = "http://my.domain.com/templates/default/login.aspx";
            loginform.username.name = "UserName";
            loginform.password.name = "Password";
            break;
        case 2:
            loginform.action = "http://voicepanel.domain.com";
            loginform.username.name = "email";
            loginform.password.name = "password";
            break;
        default:
            loginform.action = "https://www.domain.com/clients/dologin.php?goto=clientarea";
            loginform.username.name = "username";
            loginform.password.name = "password";
            break;
    }
}

function loginSubmit()
{
    var user = document.getElementsByName("username");
    var pass = document.getElementsByName("password");

    if(!user[0].value)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(!pass[0].value)
    {
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById("frmLogin").frmLogin.submit();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<!--Start Header-->
<div id="header">
<a href="index.php" id="logo"><span class="text_in">XFS</span></a>

<!--User Login-->
<div id="header_right">
    <h2><span class="text_in">User Login</span></h2>

    <form method="POST" name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin" onSubmit="javascript:loginSubmit();">
        <input class="binput" name="username" style="margin-left: 40px;" value="Username">
        <input class="binput" name="password" type="password" value="Password">
            <select class="binput" style="margin-left: 40px; width: 130px;" onchange="javascript:changeAction(this);">
                <option value="0">Billing Panel</option>
                <option value="1">Game Panel</option>
                <option value="2">Ventrilo Panel</option>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" class="blogin" value="Login" id="ButtonLogin">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake, my switch statement in the Java script was on a non-existing variable.

Answer (score 0):

sites have different ways of login .for example VBulletin hash user's password! Some other use lot's of hidden text fields! so, when you want  to send data, you should be sure all data are present!
one of ways to do it, is creating multiple forms and just show the one user want to see!